# How to substitute an event-based class for an observable-based class in C# and System.Reactive?

Tags: c#, events, design-patterns, observable, system.reactive

I have a class which has some events. At present, I decide to shift towards "Observables" since the benefits they propose. To reach this goal, I introduced an Observable property to be replaced with one of the events. Next, I made the event "private" to restrict its accessibility from out of the class. The event is invoked inside the class with a function when it is needed. However, I think It may be a better way to do this job. What is the proper practice? By the way, I am a novice in "System.Reactive," so if I have a misunderstanding with the concept, please clarify the matter.  My code is below:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass()
    {
        InformationSenderObservable=Observable.FromEventPattern<SolutionEventArg>(ev =>InformationSender += ev, ev => InformationSender -= ev);
    }
    private event EventHandler<SolutionEventArg> InformationSender;
    public IObservable<EventPattern<SolutionEventArg>> InformationSenderObservable { get; }

    internal void DoSomething()
    {
        // long calculation
        SendInformation();
    }

    private void SendInformation()
    {
        InformationSender?.Invoke(this,new SolutionEventArg()
            {
                InfoProxyData = GetDetailsForBestCompressedData(),
                ParallelProcess = parallelProcessing
            });
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason that you use the `InformationSender` event is because you don't know any other way to send information to the observable? In that case you could consider using a `Subject<T>`, which is both an observable and an observer.

Comment: Theodor Zoulias Yes, I use events before to send information from this class to other classes. However, I do not know what the best practice for the replacement of events with observables is. I avoid  ```Subject<T>``` since I have read it violates the single responsibility pattern for a class. Please clarify this matter for me.

Comment: From my experience the subjects are working perfectly in practice. What you want is a hot observable that can propagate unique notifications to all of its subscribers, and an out-of-the-box subject can do it efficiently and with thread-safety. Disclaimer: I am not an RX theoretician. :-)

Comment: Correction: the subjects are not synchronized out of the box. If you are producing notifications from multiple threads concurrently, you must offer a synchronized subject to the consumers: `public IObservable<SomeType> TheStreamOfEvents => _subject.Synchronize();`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Theodor Zoulias, I finally understood how I could better handle my class. I used `ISubject<T>`  instead of events in my class to send information from my class to another class subscribing to the `ISubject<T>`.

```
public class MyClass
    {
        public MyClass()
        {
            InformationSenderObservable=new Subject<SolutionEventArg>();
        }
        
        public ISubject<SolutionEventArg> InformationSenderObservable { get; }

        internal void DoSomething()
        {
            // long calculation
            SendInformation();
        }

        private void SendInformation()
        {
            try
            {
                InformationSenderObservable.OnNext(new SolutionEventArg()
                {
                    InfoProxyData = GetDetailsForBestCompressedData(),
                    ParallelProcess = parallelProcessing
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                InformationSenderObservable.OnError(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

`ISubject<T>` implements both `IObservable<T>` and `IObserver<T>` simultaneously.

Comment: You may want to expose an `IObservable<SolutionEventArg>` instead of an `ISubject<SolutionEventArg>`, otherwise a naughty consumer could start sending notifications to other subscribers on behalf of the `MyClass`. :-) In a low-trust environment you could consider hiding completely the identity of the underlying subject, by using the `AsObservable` operator (to prevent consumers from casting the `IObservable` to `ISubject`).

Answer (score 1):

Using the advice of @Theodor-Zoulias we make the subject private and only expose the observable through the public property. This provides the expected separation of observable and observer that is expected in reactive pattern. This is why the documentation advises not to use `Subject` in production. You can do it, if you do it correctly.

```
public class MyClass
{
    private Subject<SolutionEventArg> _informationSender;

    public MyClass()
    {
        _informationSender = new Subject<SolutionEventArg>();
    }
    
    public IObservable<SolutionEventArg> InformationSenderObservable => _informationSender.AsObservable();

    internal void DoSomething()
    {
        // long calculation
        SendInformation();
    }

    private void SendInformation()
    {
        try
        {
            InformationSenderObservable.OnNext(new SolutionEventArg()
            {
                InfoProxyData = GetDetailsForBestCompressedData(),
                ParallelProcess = parallelProcessing
            });
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            InformationSenderObservable.OnError(e);
        }
    }
}
```